# Visual Studio Test using Test Agent

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, tfs

I have a situation : I have two servers (server A and server B) and my TFS making build of my application on **server A** and should deploy the results on **server B**. After that it should run UI tests remotely.
For doing that I use TFS 2015 and I added a few steps for my build definition (if you understand what i mean ))) ).

- Firs step is "Visual Studio Build" step which is build my project. -> is working fine
- The second step is "Publish Build Artifacts" for publishing the build results from server A to server B (maybe it is not best solution for publishing something between machines but is working for me. If you have some advice for that, I will be appreciate to hear it).-> is working fine
- Third step is "Visual Studio Test Agent Deployment" which should deploy Test Agent on **server B**. When this step is runed it shows **'agentlocation' is not a valid path. Ensure that the account with which build agent is running has access to this share.** And the all if fails on this step but root to file **vstf_testagent.exe** is acceseble by everyone (For sharing of this folder was set Everyone Read/Write).
- Fourth step is "Visual Studio test using Test Agent" which should run my UI tests. I hope that this step can run my UI tests.

on server A I installed Test Controller and on server B I installed Test Agent and gave him name of Test Controller. On server A I use Visual Studio 2015 but on server B I use Visual Studio 2013.

Please help me to understand problem with third step. What can it be and how to resolve it?
And can step fourth run my UI tests?

Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 0):

The field of "Test Agent Location" is optionally, which is used to supply the path to vstf_testagent.exe from network or local location. If no path is provided, it will be downloaded from network. You can leave this field blank and let it download from network, maybe you can deploy a test agent successfully.